# Writing XML file with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I am trying to use a XML file, and write out the information on my website using HTML. This if for a school project, and the teacher spesifically told us to use XML and HTML. My HTML already contains code, pictures, text etc, and this works perfectly. So i tried to put the XML code inside a  tag, and write it out. The XML file is just a table with some information about my favourite basketballball players.

I have searched through the internet for a couple of days now, and I couldnt find any information about this topic. I visited the W3Schools site and I tried using the information given there.

The problem is when I use what they have done there, try to expand it, and make it work with my own tags, it wont work, at all! For example, when i have two tags in the XML file, and try to write that out, it works. Then i try to add just one more tag, and the whole thing just shuts down. The only that appears is a little black square.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<basketballplayers>
<player>
  <name>Steve Nash</name>
  <college>Santa Clara</college>
  <team>La Lakers</team>
</player>
<player>
  <name>Ricky Rubio</name>
  <college>Did not attend</college>
  <team>Minnesota Timberwolves</team>
</player>
<player>
  <name>Michael Jordan</name>
  <college>North Carolina</college>
  <team>Chicago Bulls</team>
</player>
</basketballplayers>
```

And here is my HTML code, with just the XML stuff:

```
            <script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "proving.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.write("<table border='1'>");

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("player");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("college")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td></tr>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("team")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td></tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
            </script>

        </div>
```

Comment: don't use `document.write`. Once page is loaded it will wipe everything out!

Comment: Huh? No it won't. Anyway... change your first `document.write("</td></tr>");` to `document.write("</td><td>");`

Comment: @rjdown it won't? Then explain what happens in this demo  http://plnkr.co/edit/NNvJgW7uCXM7r1rksEXy?p=preview

Comment: If you check Pureiya's example, you'll see it's inline (note the closing div), so it will write to the current document. In your plnkr example, your use of setTimeout means the call is being used after the document has closed, and therefore a new one is created instead. More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing jquery js library ,

Try

```
$.get("proving.xml", null, null, "xml")
.done(function (xml, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    $("body").append("<table id=result border=1></table>");
    $(xml).find("player *").each(function (i, el) {
        $("#result").append("<tr><td>" + el.textContent + "</td></tr>")
    })
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/w6nx71pd/